# Having problems with RotateTransform3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I'm making a program in which, I'm trying to implement several transformations on ModelVisual3D. I have no problem with TranslateTransform3D, but when I try to rotate an object(ModelVisual3D) its CenterX, CenterY and CenterZ coordinates are going to 0,0,0. I don't have any idea how to remember the last position of the object and when I rotate it, the object stay there where I translated it. I implemented rotate of an object to be when LeftMouseButton is double clicked, but rotation is executing only once.Here is the peace of code, which corresponds for RotateTransform:

```
MyViewport.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (modelHit != null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {

        Point endPosition = e.GetPosition(gridDesigner);
        Vector3D vector3D = GetTranslationVector3D(modelHit, startPosition, endPosition);

        Matrix3D matrix3D = modelHit.Transform.Value;
        vector3D += new Vector3D(matrix3D.OffsetX, matrix3D.OffsetY, matrix3D.OffsetZ);

        matrix3D.OffsetX = vector3D.X;
        matrix3D.OffsetY = 0.2f;
        matrix3D.OffsetZ = vector3D.Z;
        modelHit.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(matrix3D);
        startPosition = endPosition;

        MyViewport.MouseLeftButtonDown += (Sender, m) =>
            {
                if (modelHit != null && m.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    RotateTransform3D rotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D();
                    AxisAngleRotation3D axisAngleRotation=new AxisAngleRotation3D();

                    Matrix3D modelHitCoordinates = modelHit.Transform.Value;
                    rotateTransform.CenterX = modelHitCoordinates.OffsetX;
                    rotateTransform.CenterY = 0.1;
                    rotateTransform.CenterZ = modelHitCoordinates.OffsetZ;

                    axisAngleRotation.Axis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
                    axisAngleRotation.Angle = 0;
                    rotateTransform.Rotation = axisAngleRotation;

                    if  (m.ClickCount == 2)
                    {
                        axisAngleRotation.Angle += 45;
                        modelHit.Transform = rotateTransform;

                    }

                }
            };
    }
};
```

Comment: A pure, simple rotation is always around the origin (0,0,0). If you want to rotate some object around its "center" (supposing you know the position of center), you have to transform it so that the centr is coinciding with the system's origin, then rotate, and then translate it back.

Comment: @heltonbiker No. The Transform method does allow you to specify a rotation center, so it does the transforms you are describing internally (if you use the correct types, see below).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the type you are transforming. If your type is a "Vector3D" then the Transform method will ignore the rotation center. I don't think this is correctly documented.

Both the type you are rotating and the Center have to be of type "Point3D".

The intent of the writer of that method is legit. A direction in space (a "Vector3D") should not depend on the center of rotation, so the extra translation of the rotation center should not be necessary. If you rotate a location in 3D space (a "Point3D") however, then the center of rotation does matter.